# Can SslBundle in Spring Boot 3.1.x support customized KeyStore

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot has the SslBundle abstraction, to load keystore/truststore from files or remote locations. However, if using a customized KeyStore implementation like Azure Key Vault KeyStore, seems like can configure it with the Spring Boot `spring.ssl.bundle.jks.` proeprties. Does it support customized keystore type, which doesn't have a `jks` file?

As in method [JksSslStoreBundle.loadKeyStore](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/e1bd24695de7d91ce1f405d4997ffab31ae28f81/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/ssl/jks/JksSslStoreBundle.java#L116-L119), it only allows to load the keystore from a non-null stream, and there's no way to call another method in `KeyStoreSpi`

```java
// KeyStoreSpi.java
public void engineLoad(KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter param)
                throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                CertificateException {
    engineLoad(null, param);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use properties for this. To use a customized `KeyStore`, create an  `SslBundleRegistrar` implementation that registers a bundle that's backed by the custom `KeyStore`. The registrar should be defined as a bean and it will then be called to register its bundles when the application starts. You can use `SslStoreBundle.of(KeyStore, String, KeyStore)` to create the bundle of trust material and `SslBundle.of(SslStoreBundle)` to create a bundle from it.